# spring statemachine data jpa sample issues

Tags: spring-boot, spring-statemachine

I am trying to get the [spring statemachine data jpa sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-statemachine/tree/master/spring-statemachine-samples/datajpa/src) working and I am unable to. I have created a sample [github project](https://github.com/adeelmahmood/statemachine-jpa-test) here. So far, I have only added the necessary dependencies and getting this error:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.statemachine.data.StateRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound (DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1493)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency (DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1104)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency (DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject (AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject (InjectionMetadata.java:88)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues (AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)

Comment: Thanks for the sample. I see same when running it and, afaik, it should work. Lemmy try to figure out what happens here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you already figured this out but you're missing jpa libs. Those can be added i.e. using `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`